# Why does zero-initialization happen even when base has a user-declared constructor?

Tags: c++

This prints `0`, meaning `data` was zero-initialization. Why does this happen even when `base` has a user-declared constructor?

```c++
struct base
{
    base() { }
    int data;
};

struct derived : base
{
    derived() = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << derived().data;
}
```

If `derived` has a user-declared constructor then it prints out a random value. Why does zero-initialization depend on the derived class and not the base class?

Comment: It doesn't happen.  UB has many possible outcomes, 0 is just one of them.

Comment: Best to avoid this issue altogether and provide a constructor initialization list, IMO.

Comment: FYI, you're missing a `;` after `default` and a `#include <iostream>`

Comment: `This prints 0, meaning data was zero-initialization.`  0 is as good a number as 234324235 when it comes to uninitialized variables.

Comment: There is no UB in the code above, `data` is required to be zero-initialized by the standard. [dcl.init]/8 "(8.2)
— if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then
the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if
T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rules were specifically written to cover

```
struct S {
  int i;
  std::string s;
};
```

where without any user-provided constructor, even though the implicitly generated default constructor is non-trivial, `S().i` would be zero-initialised. This cannot depend on the constructor of `int`, since `int` doesn't have any constructor. The decision was made to let it depend on whether the class `S` has a user-provided constructor. There's not much else it could depend on.

What you're seeing is a simple consequence of that. Your class `derived` also has no user-provided constructor, so it gets zero initialisation too.

Comment: Indeed, changing `derived`'s constructor to `derived() : base() {}` (i.e. making it a user-provided constructor) results in an uninitialized `data` member.